# SQL Server Create Login using inserted values from Trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of users in sql serevr 2012 and wish to create corresponding database login users using inserted values from an insert trigger on the users table.

Everything seems to work ok except that I cannot properly use a referenced value in the inserted table
though I have tested the value to make sure it exists

is it possible that the create login procedure cannot accept variables

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[addsyslogin] 
   ON [dbo].[Users]
   FOR  INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF;

    Declare @u varchar(10);
    SELECT @u=i.userid from inserted i;


    print @u;

CREATE LOGIN [@u] WITH PASSWORD='water123GH', DEFAULT_DATABASE=[waterdb], DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[British], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=ON


END
```

I have researched on quoted_identifiers but I still have this problem.

What happens is that a database user is actually created with userid=@u instead of the value in @u.

Thanks for your notes and feedback

Comment: Triggers MUST handle multiple rows

Comment: Just as a note - if you insert 2 users, the trigger will fire only once, but the inserted table will contain 2 rows. Your code is not expecting this.

Comment: BTW, you can't use a param like that in a CREATE LOGIN statement...

Comment: I insert the users from an asp.net mvc page so at each time.only 1 insert is done..I have tested this and it works fine.problem is the value in the @u does not seem to store the user id.It seems to me as a programmatic error but cant figure out what it is

Comment: ok Mitch....that means create login cannot accept variables? for the login name

Comment: cant we start a debate on why your users really don't need their own sql logins? hello connection pool spam goodbye proven membership providers...

Comment: Hello BobTodd,I want the database to create efficient and detailed logs on every crud on any table so i guess their own logins on the server will best do this .....else I would have to handle programmatically.....by inserting stuffs into the logs table instead of the trigger doing that for me using the login of the user....tell me of your experience and a better way of doing this..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SET @SQL = 'CREATE LOGIN ' + @u+ ' WITH PASSWORD = ''water123GH'', DEFAULT_DATABASE=[waterdb], DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[British], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=ON';
EXECUTE(@SQL);
```

Comment: dynamic SQL in a trigger! You are so going to TSQL hell!

Comment: aww, but userid was created with a sql parameter valued ";drop database water" :p

Comment: kinda agree but that will solve his problem. I would never create a login on a trigger, BUT we don't know his reality. Maybe for some creepy reason its his only possibility.

Comment: I am trying...Will be back with feedback..No creepy reasons..Just to make sure the created database users are effective as soon a successful user is created in the database table..I was also having problems handling this from entity framework..thats why I choose this way...I am not an expert sql guy...

Comment: Thanks Diego...I am so dump...I have Dropped the trigger and using the sql statement like that..And for all the feedback...u guys rock over here..

Comment: @Diego Could i use this in a stored Proc? http://stackoverflow.com/q/10930669/1356321

Answer (score 0):

This is a curious thing to do, but you need to...

- allow for multiple rows
- escalate privileges
- use dynamic SQL

Other notes:

- I'd suggest that you need a separate stored procedure in master called by your trigger to deal with the escalation
- If you don't require escalation, then your privileges are too high

Rough code:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[addsyslogin] ON [dbo].[Users] FOR  INSERT
WITH EXECUTE AS --soemthing
AS 
SET NOCOUNT ON;

Declare @u varchar(10), @uid int;

SELECT TOP 1 @uid = i.userid, @u = i.userid
FROM inserted i
ORDER BY i.userid;

WHILE @u IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SET @SQL = 'CREATE LOGIN ' + @u+ ' WITH PASSWORD = ''water123GH'', DEFAULT_DATABASE=[waterdb], DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[British], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=ON';

    EXECUTE(@SQL);

    SET @u = NULL;

    SELECT TOP 1 @uid = i.userid, @u = i.userid
    FROM inserted i
    WHERE i.userid > @uid
    ORDER BY i.userid;

 END

 GO
```