# I am trying to create a stored procedure to create a login and a database user? 

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am developing a C# application with SQL Server, and would like to call a stored procedure to create a login and a user.

I am looking for the simplest way to do this, just default stuff but have username and password.

The create next to login is underlined in red?

But I think my login is fine? Please tell me if I'm missing something.

And with the create user, is it just a one liner like that?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CreateLoginAndUser 
       @UserName

   CREATE LOGIN @UserName 
   WITH PASSWORD = 'password', 
        DEFAULT_DATABASE = [TestAudit],
        DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = [British],
        CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF,
        CHECK_POLICY=ON;

   CREATE USER 'DEV' + @UserName 
       [{ FOR | FROM } LOGIN @UserName] [WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = schema]
```

I don't understand `FOR` and `FROM` ...

Could I do something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CreateLoginAndUser
     @UserName

    CREATE LOGIN @UserName  
    WITH PASSWORD = 'password', 
         DEFAULT_SCHEMA = schema    

    CREATE USER 'DEV'+@UserName 
       [{ FOR | FROM } LOGIN @UserName] [WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = schema]
```

How have Googled the following sources:

http://ss64.com/sql/login_c.html

http://ss64.com/sql/user_c.html

Comment: do you want to create new user account thorough stored procedure? Your problem is not much clear.

Comment: Check out: [Basic SQL Server Security concepts - logins, users, and principals](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lcris/archive/2007/03/23/basic-sql-server-security-concepts-logins-users-and-principals.aspx). A **login** is a server-wide object; a **user** is for a single database only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider using dymanic SQL to create a user.  For example, to create a server login called `@login` with a database user called `'DEV' + @login`:

```
create procedure dbo.CreateLoginAndUser(
        @login varchar(100),
        @password varchar(100),
        @db varchar(100))
as
declare @safe_login varchar(200)
declare @safe_password varchar(200)
declare @safe_db varchar(200)
set @safe_login = replace(@login,'''', '''''')
set @safe_password = replace(@password,'''', '''''')
set @safe_db = replace(@db,'''', '''''')

declare @sql nvarchar(max)
set @sql = 'use ' + @safe_db + ';' +
           'create login ' + @safe_login + 
               ' with password = ''' + @safe_password + '''; ' +
           'create user DEV' + @safe_login + ' from login ' + @safe_login + ';'
exec (@sql)
go
```

It might be easier to construct the SQL statement client-side.  But even then, you couldn't use parameters with the `create login` statement.  So be on your guard about SQL Injection.

Comment: Well there are no red underlined words so that's gr8 +1 :D, could you explain what the ''''''' is for? with regards to  set @safe_login = replace(@login,'''', '''''')

Comment: i Really need to know what the '''' means and where i can specify the user can use. and if i need to add DEFAULT_SCHEMA = schema  anywhere?

Comment: Database added.  DEFAULT_SCHEMA is optional.  If you're not into schema's (and you shouldn't be) don't go near it.

Comment: ,I think i need it, The program i'm writing searches schema's. do i need to replace the '''' with something or is that how it should be?

Comment: In SQL strings you've got to escape `'` like `''`.  So the `''''` is as it should be: a string containing two single quotes.

Comment: Had you got the error like - "USE database statement is not allowed in a procedure" as posted here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60062977/how-to-grant-user-access-to-a-db-from-inside-a-stored-procedure-in-sql-server-g?

Answer (score 1):

{ FOR | FROM } means you can use for or from.

| (vertical bar) =  Separates syntax items enclosed in brackets or braces. You can use only one of the items.

EDIT:

I should have added that they are synonyms, you can use any of them, the result is the same

Answer (score 0):

You should consider user rights. To create sql server login and database user, you have to have high privileges on SQL Server instance. So either you have to grant user rights to do the action (and that mean- server level and database lever permissions) or you have to use other mechanism not to make your server vulnerable.

One of the option's would be using certificates and signet stored procedures to do things "nicely" and not allow creation of logins/users directly.

Also, the one who is able to use trace, will be able to see passwords (if you are not wrapping that in procedure, password is not shown in trace).

Answer (score 0):

here is an example on how to create a login for the server-wide, and a user for your db
adapt it to a procedure

```
USE [master]
GO
CREATE LOGIN [usr] WITH PASSWORD=N'pass', DEFAULT_DATABASE=[yourDb], DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[English], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF
GO

USE [yourDb]
GO
CREATE USER [usr] FOR LOGIN ['usr]
GO
```

you only have to receive usr and password as a parameter and use it