# Stored procedure for a login with user and password as parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
create procedure createacc(
@loginnaam nvarchar(30),
@wachtwoord nvarchar(30))
AS
CREATE LOGIN @loginnaam
WITH PASSWORD = @wachtwoord
CREATE USER @loginnaam FOR LOGIN @loginnaam
ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD @loginnaam
Go
```

This gives me syntax errors while it works fine outside of the Stored Procedure.

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure createacc, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near '@loginnaam'.
Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Procedure createacc, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure createacc, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ADD'.
```

Comment: Which dbms? (Doesn't look like ANSI/ISO SQL...)

Comment: Looks like you are using SQL Server, add this tag please.

Comment: And unclear what do you want? If you want create user account in stored proc, then you should use dynSQL through `sp_executesql`

Comment: Added the tag, not sure what you means dbms, I'm just trying to create this script in Microsoft Management Studio for SQL

The problem is that this procedure can't be created because it tells me there's an syntax error, but I know that the code doesn't have any syntax error so I'd figure it is because I'm trying to do it with a procedure, but I can't find out why.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I am trying to create a stored procedure to create a login and a database user?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10930669/i-am-trying-to-create-a-stored-procedure-to-create-a-login-and-a-database-user)

Comment: You have syntax error "createacc(" "(" symbol should be removed from the procedure name

Comment: Fixed that one now Oleg, I also pasted my error window.

Comment: You miss the closing ')' for the create statement; the signature of the procedure must be terminated before the AS keyword

Comment: Done that Paola, and put the current code in, errors are still the same, also Maciej I had found that link while searching for a solution but it seems a bit overcomplicated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using dynamic sql for this. Declare a nvarchar variable, put your statement inside it and execute that statement.
For example in your case:

```
DECLARE @statement NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @statement = 'CREATE LOGIN ' + @loginnaam + ' WITH PASSWORD = '''+ @wachtwoord + ''' ;'
exec (@statement)
```

Comment: It is truly duplicated question as @maciej-nowicki said in comment

Comment: Okay, so why a minus to my answer.The comment was not there when I started to give my answer. Is my answer wrong?

Comment: I said for example in his case. I did for one case. I am not here to provide him full working code for his work.

Comment: Thank you, sorry if it was indeed a duplicate but I did not understand how the link provided by Maciej worked.

Answer (score 0):

Above answer may be velnarable to SQL injection, it is concating SQL statement and then executing it.
Is there any way to pass password string as a parameter like example below

```
 declare @query nvarchar(500)
 declare @params nvarchar(500)
 declare @passwordVal nvarchar(100)
 set @passwordVal=N'Test@123'
 set @query = 'Alter LOGIN  [SqlUser] WITH password=@pass'
 set @params =  N'@pass NVARCHAR (100)';
 EXECUTE sp_executesql @query,@params, @pass=@passwordVal
```

This query generates error

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '@pass'.

Better alternative answer to parameter is here

[I am trying to create a stored procedure to create a login and a database user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10930669/i-am-trying-to-create-a-stored-procedure-to-create-a-login-and-a-database-user?noredirect=1&lq=1)